# how compare datetime from firebird db to current date in Delphi

Tags: delphi

In firebird 3.0 db in Timestamp type field saved data. How compare this data to current date?

```
 if  (Query1data1.AsDateTime <>date()) then ...
```

Comment: `if Trunc(Query1.fieldbyname('timestampfield').AsDatetime) <> Dateof(Now) then...`

Comment: @nolaspeaker `DateOf(Now())` is the same as `Date()`. And if you use `AsDateTime` to read the field, you could use `DateOf()` instead of `Trunc()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ignore the time of day, may use [CompareDate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.DateUtils.CompareDate).

> Indicates the relationship between the date portions of two TDateTime values.
>
> Call CompareDate to compare the two TDateTime values specified by A
>   and B. CompareDate returns:
>
> LessThanValue if A occurs on a day prior to the day specified by B.
>   EqualsValue if A occurs on the same day as B, ignoring the time of
>   day. GreaterThanValue if A occurs on a day that follows the day
>   specified by B.

For example :

```
case CompareDate(Query1data1.FieldByName('TIMESTAMP_FIELD').AsDateTime,Date()) of  
    -1 : ShowMessage('is less');
    0 : ShowMessage('equals');
    1 : ShowMessage('is greater')                
  end;
```

Also you may use: [DateOf](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.DateUtils.DateOf)

> Strips the time portion from a TDateTime value.
>
> Call DateOf to convert a TDateTime value to a TDateTime value that
>   includes only the date information (sets the time portion to 0, which
>   means midnight).

```
if DateOf(Query1data1.FieldByName('FTIMESTAMP').AsDateTime) = Date() then
    ....
```